# Реализация пошагового ввода информации

Tags: android, android-fragment

Каким образом можно реализовать пошаговый ввод информации?(На первой странице один блок, на второй - второй и т.д.). Есть идея сделать через viewpager и фрагменты, но не могу понять, как в конце собрать все данные воедино...

Comment: какого рода данные? зависит от их дальнейшего использования. Можно в БД писать на каждом шаге, а когда потребуется извлечь целиком или в хост-активити фрагментов организовать динамическое хранилище на основе ArrayList, если данные нужны только на одну сессию

Comment: Данные примитивных типов, далее передача по api. Данные нужны на одну сессию. "в хост-активити фрагментов организовать динамическое хранилище на основе ArrayList" - попробую данный вариант, спасибо

Comment: А вообще, правильно ли реализовывать таким способом? или есть более подходящие?

Comment: более или менее подходящие способы можно предложить, если вы более подробно опишите вашу задачу. какие именно данные, объем данных, последующее использование и тп.

Comment: Требуется собрать данные о посылке и передать их по api через xml. Т.к. данных много(ФИО отправителя\получателя, город отправления\доставки, адреса, габариты груза и т.д), лучше разделить их на блоки и заполнять частями. Вот как можно реализовать пошаговое заполнение, чтобы в конце данные были сконсолидированы и их можно было отправить?